# Create GridView rows using GridViewRow object in Code Behind Using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a GridView Control in Code Behind.

Data is fetched from database table.

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class gv1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection cn;
   SqlCommand cmd;
   DataSet ds;
   SqlDataAdapter da;

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AMIR-PC\\MOHEMMAD;Initial Catalog=CRM_InvestPlus;Integrated Security=True");

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Customer_Master", cn);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    cn.Close();

    GridView gr1 = new GridView();

    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(i, i, DataControlRowType.DataRow,  DataControlRowState.Normal);
        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
        TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
        cell1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
        cell2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
        row.Cells.Add(cell1);
        row.Cells.Add(cell2);
        gr1.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(i, row);


      }
        this.Controls.Add(gr1);
   }
}
```

But when I Run the code error occurs as follows:

ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user at the line of code showing

gr1.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(i,row);

Please help..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: have you tried debugging the code and checking the values of variables on each iteration?

Comment: yes i have tried that but the actual thing is that i don't know actual working of `gr1.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(i, row);`  @asma

Comment: Okay, try my answer which I just posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this occurs because you are adding to `Control[0]` that is not set anywhere. Change it like this and see if it helps:

<strike>gr1.Controls.AddAt(i, row);</strike>

Ok this is how it should like:

First when you are initializing your grid view you have to add to it `Table`

```
var gv = new GridView();
var t = new Table();
gv.Controls.Add(t);
```

Then you can add you row the way you were doing

```
gv.Controls[0].AddAt(i, row);
```

Please try this way :)

Comment: it generates new error displaying this message
"Control 'ctl02' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server." @gzaxx

Comment: Does your from in `HTML` looks like that `<form runat="server">`?

Comment: yes absolutely sir..

`<form id="form1" runat="server">`

@gzaxx

Comment: Change this line `this.Controls.Add(gr1);` it to this (in code behind): `form1.Controls.Add(gr1);`

Comment: Tried the above line and got the error...
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table'." @gzaxx

Comment: Can you please help me to make the template cell.. I mean I want to add a FileUploadControl in generated GridView @gzaxx

Comment: Well for more complicated `GridView`s I would not do them from code but use a designer. Just create your own data source that would fill it properly. Otherwise I can't help you much more because I've never ever done what are you asking for :(.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try a simpler code?

```
if(ds.tables.count > 0)
    {
    gr1.DataSource = ds;
    gr1.DataBind();

    }
else
{
  lable.Text = "No Record Found";
}
```

Comment: I have tried both the lines above but the same error is generated.. @asma

Comment: Check my edited answer please
Upted it once again. It's finalized now. You can give it a try

Comment: My basic need is that i want to decide the size of gridview(no. of rows) in code behind file.. @asma

Comment: So at the end, do you need the row count?

Comment: I cant understand what did you suggest. The need is ....
Consider a case that the table Customer_Master table contains the "Capacity" field. If the Customer C0001 has the Capacity 5 then I want 5 rows in gridview.. @asma